# difficulty in printing in a 5x3

Tags: c++

[this is the output i want to do :/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq4Nj.jpg)

i uploaded an image :/ why doesnt preview

sample output:
1)AUD  6)     11)

2)     7)     12)

3)     8     13
4)     9     14
5)     10    11)PHP

hi im making a table for choices and im kinda stuck in this part(finishing touch)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROW = 15;
    const int COL = 15;
    float magicArray1[ROW][COL];
    int choice1,choice2;
    float amount,result;
    //

    char currency_name[15][5] = 
    {   "AUD","BRL","CAD","CNY","DKK","EUR","HKD","INR","JPY","RUR","SGD","SEK",
    "CHF","USD","PHP"

    };

    //

    cout << "Available Currencies:" << endl;
        cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    for(int j = 0; j <5; j++)
        {
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
            cout << i+1 << ". " << currency_name[i][j] <<endl;
            }
        }
    //



    return 0;
}
```

can someone point out my error :D and give me a hint :D
im kinda puzzled right now 
this is all i have now

Comment: If you would post the desired output as text it would help you to figure out what to do. So open a text editor and type in the desired output. Fill gaps with tabs (or spaces). Now imagine that you are a typing machine. You can type one character at a time and you need to finish a row before jumping onto next one. Repeat the same exercise as if you were a typing machine. After that you will handle the coding part easily.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the expected output *as text*. And include the *actual* output as well. And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: are you trying to use the array `currency_name[15]` to print the sequence in the image?

Comment: my bad im using currency_name[15][5]

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted here works just fine.
But the following code is enough to do what you want it to do.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string currency_name[15] =
    {
        "AUD","BRL","CAD","CNY","DKK","EUR","HKD","INR","JPY","RUR","SGD","SEK",
        "CHF","USD","PHP"
    };

    cout << "Available Currencies:" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << ". " << currency_name[i] <<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i knew it!! figuring how to put it in a 5x3 hmm

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string currency_name[15][5] =
    {
        "AUD","BRL","CAD","CNY","DKK","EUR","HKD","INR","JPY","RUR","SGD","SEK",
        "CHF","USD","PHP"
    };

    cout << "Available Currencies:" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for( int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            cout << j+1 << ". " << currency_name[i][j] <<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

yey!!! my problem is the numbering now :/